# Writing objects that extend LinkedList

Tags: c++

I have issue with my code, which I am going to attempt reduction to conceptual question.

I have a class called `PunctuationOccurrenceList`, which is a `LinkedList` of `PunctuationOccurrence`s. `PunctuationOccurrence` is merely a data class that has no pointers whatsoever.

`LinkedList` has destructor that looks like:

```
template <class Object>
LinkedList<Object>::~LinkedList()
{
    /* Here, you could just delete the headerNode, since everything else is linked to it (the point of a LinkedList!!), and will
    * also be deleted!! */
    if (this->headerNode)
        delete this->headerNode;
    this->lastNode = 0;
}
```

`LinkedList` has `ListNode`s that have destructor:

```
template <class Object>
ListNode<Object>::~ListNode()
{
    if (this->nextNode)
        delete this->nextNode;
}
```

I had to write copy constructor for `PunctuationOccurrenceList`. However, when a `PunctuationOccurrenceList` goes out of scope, things get weird. When testing the `PunctuationOccurrenceList` module, it works just fine. However, when used as an object member of another class, if it is not empty, segmentation fault happens.

I know that the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) says that I should write copy constructor. How should I write it?

Comment: Since your `LinkedList` is a container, your destructor should delete all the nodes, not only 1.

Comment: Post your code with the declaration of the `linkedlist` data members.

Comment: Your destructor for `ListNode` doesn't make sense because it is delete another object, not itself.

Comment: `delete this` would cause infinite recursion.

Comment: What @ThomasMatthews is saying is that your node destructor is actually deleting another node (referring to `delete this->nextNode`). Each node should preferably be responsible for itself only (actually, its members), and the LinkedList should be the one to traverse all nodes and call `delete node`. Lastly and FWIW, that's not the cause of your problem. How are you allocating each node - with `new ListNode<...>()`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews destructor for ListNode does make  sense. Assuming the `nextNode` is also a ListNode*, what happens is that the structure is recursively deleted (if this code would ever get into a place with limited stack - embedded or device drivers - then ... welcome to stackoverflow)

Comment: In a well formed design, an object should only delete its members, such as data fields.  The destruction of nodes should be the responsibility of the list class, IMO.

Comment: Beyond that, you should edit your question to include a minimal compilable/runnable sample that demonstrates the problem you're seeing. This would help people here detect and point to possible mistakes or gotchas you must pay attention to.

Answer (score 2):

LinkedList's copy constructor should create a copy of the whole list; it should duplicate every node in the original list.

Comment: `LinkedList` has `headNode` and `lastNode`. I changed the copy constructor for `LinkedList` to actually deep-copy `this->lastNode` and the destructor to actually delete it.